# Does anyone have a brake line diagram for a 2000 Monte Carlo SS?

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, abs, replacements, monte-carlo

The left rear brake line on our 00 MC rusted through and caused a loss of brake fluid and stopping power. Luckily, the car wasn't far from the house when it happened so my son was able to limp home.

I ordered a complete brake line set and am now removing all of the brake lines to replace them.

One thing I noticed, though. On the ABS master cylinder, the lines don't appear to be connected to the correct channels. I thought that the rear lines would be together on one channel and the front lines would be on the other channel. That way, a loss of brake fluid on one channel will leave you with enough braking power on the other. On my 00 MC, it appears that the left side brake lines are on one channel and the right side lines are on the other.

The previous owner of the car had told me he'd had one of the brake lines replaced before so I'm wondering if his mechanic didn't put things together correctly.

See the attached drawing. I'm assuming that 1/2 are on one channel and 3/4 are on the other on the ABS master cylinder.

The way this is set up, a loss of brake fluid loss on the left rear would cause a loss of braking power on the left side of the car so braking would pull the car to one side. Or am I my misunderstanding in that in the case of an ABS system it doesn't matter because the ABS will compensate for any situation?

Does anybody have a brake line diagram for a 2000 Monte Carlo SS starting from the ABS master cylinder?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: One possibility is if the fronts have two pistons is that one channel does a front left and right with one rear, the other does the other front L+R and the other rear to balance in case of a channel loss.

Comment: @Solar Mike are you saying that it is possible to have 2 seperate lines at each front caliper on this vehicle?

Comment: That year Monte Carlo uses the Delphi DBC 7 BPMV. The lines from the master are seperated rf/lr and lf/rr. Can you provide pictures of how the lines were setup before? Or is the drawing how it was? Usually the BPMV is labeled and it's pretty hard to mess up replacing a single brake line.

Comment: @Milison as I said "one possibility..." and yes, some cars do have twin pot calipers that have individual connections to each pot so you can have better control... IIRC the range rover won awards for a split braking system like that - you can easily tell as each front wheel has two brake pipes going to it... Mind you there are 4 pot and 6 pot calipers around...

Comment: Ben, the drawing is exactly how the brake lines were set up before I removed them one by one from the ABS master cylinder and marking as I went.

Comment: Solar Mike, the braking system is standard as far as I can tell. There are two lines coming out from the brake master cylinder into the ABS master cylinder and 4 lines coming out of the ABS master cylinder, one for each wheel.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your responses. My default will be to connect the new lines I'm installing exactly as I removed them unless someone has a diagram that shows that this setup is incorrect. I think it's incorrect but absent confirmation, I'll go with the status quo.

Comment: Hopefully, if there is someone with information, they can post before I actually put things back together and bleed the entire system (both MCs and each line) so I don't have to re-bleed all over again if I have to reconfigure the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Ben, thank you! Your identification of the Delphi DBC 7 BPMV as the model of the ABS master cylinder did the trick. I found this [article][1]

[1]: https://www.aa1car.com/library/abs_delphi_dbc7.htm that has a diagram and it appears that the original setup on my 00 MC is correct.

Again, thanks. I wouldn't have found the info I needed without you.